# Warning: class_implements(): Class does not exist and could not be loaded

Tags: php, xampp, symfony-2.8

Not sure if this question belongs here, but it is kinda a programming question.

I'm running xampp 3.2.2 (just Apache and MySQL) with php 7.1.14 on Windows 7 to work on several Symfony (2.8) applications.

Initially I had them hosted with vhosts using different ports and accessed them by http://my-ip:port, but that was a PITA because 1) the browser mixes up the cookies, forcing you to continually log in when switching apps and 2) some php cache (I think, its been a while) mixes up User classes, forcing you to restart Apache.

I then switched to name-based vhosts (nothing fancy, local name resolution using C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) which got rid of the issues.

Not sure if it is related to running several apps, but now I got a new problem: Everything started out fine, but then Symfony sporadically threw this error in my face:

```
Warning: class_implements(): Class  does not exist and could not be loaded
```

Most of the time there is no class name (note the two spaces), sometimes it says some gibberish  like `\.php$`. I typed this one from memory, but I think it was a less well-formed regex. I also get other stuff that's definitely not a class name.

Over time (a few weeks), "sporadically" changed to "every few minutes/requests", even with just using one app. What helps is restarting Apache, sometimes I also need to delete the Symfony cache.

What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:
in **php.ini** file
change this line,

```
;realpath_cache_size = 4096k
```

to

```
realpath_cache_size = 4096k
```

and restart your Apache or XAMPP.

Comment: I follow the reasoning, Symfony does use a lot of files, esp. on dev. It didn't help though, will try with more

Answer (score 1):

This error was occurring in my Localserver, i just restarted the Apache and things become fine. So, you can make a try.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, but my teacher told me that if you change this in the file `/etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`, and you change the line from

```
xdebug.scream = yes
```

to

```
xdebug.scream = no
```

finally, restart PHP and Apache, and it will be solved.

Comment: I assume this is linked to _xdebug_ and in the [docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) it refers to this option as just shutting up the logging. This is not a solution to the issue but rather pushing the rubbish below the carpet, the advice your teacher gave you it is probably because the error is not critical for you. But nonetheless it is not solving the issue.

Comment: It's true, my apologies for the confusion. I thought that since disabling error debugging made the command work, it must be related to the error.